# Implement Authentication using office 0365 in AngularJS (Get login user information)

Tags: angularjs, azure, oauth, ms-office

I'm implementing `office 0365` authentication using AngularJS.
I want to make the user login to the `MS Office 0365` and get the user information from their API.
I have created application for same and all app credentials and app details are present with me.

I have tried [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) in my project but no success.

Any other solution and provide me steps for same.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @astaykov Not working on my site and I have not added any code that I know, If it is possible then provide me Any other solution and Please provide me steps for same.